# How do I investigate a failed pipeline that fails before a logging URL is created?

Tags: here-olp

I am trying to execute my new pipeline, but it is failing before I get the response that includes the logging URL.  How can I figure out why my pipeline is failing?

Comment: can you be more specific, please? Is there any code you can share?

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, please use the Splunk logs (Under tools --> logs link). 
When splunk link is populated, please use text "request_id" to retrieve the failed pipeline. If there are multiple logs, they can be filtered by the approximate time of the run request.

Should you need more assistance on Splunk syntax, please visit the tutorial [here](https://splunk.metrics.platform.here.com/en-US/help?location=%5Bolp-here%3A1.0%5Dsearch_app.tutorial).

Comment: link to splunk is not valid anymore

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to run your pipeline locally through your IDE. This can help debug errors prior to attempting to deploy your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline could be failing at some point before it is deployed - these errors should be visible under <*realm*>_central Splunk index. This is the index where Pipeline Service will push any pipeline related errors that it runs into before deployment. You can search for the Pipeline ID or Pipeline version ID to pull out relevant logs.